# IDA Pro Reverse offset in struct

Tags: ida, offset, delphi

I'm reversing a Delphi program and have a part where it says:

```
Result = *(Self - 44);
```

But I want it to say something like:

```
Result = *(Self - offsetof(VMT_ClassDefinition, vmtClassName));
```

Being VMT_ClassDefinition the following struct:

```
struct VMT_ClassDefinition {
    Cardinal vmtSelfPtr;
    Cardinal vmtIntfTable;
    Cardinal vmtAutoTable;
    Cardinal vmtInitTable;
    Cardinal vmtTypeInfo;
    Cardinal vmtFieldTable;
    Cardinal vmtMethodTable;
    Cardinal vmtDynamicTable;
    Cardinal vmtClassName;
    Cardinal vmtInstanceSize;
    Cardinal vmtParent;
    Cardinal vmtSafeCallException;
    Cardinal vmtAfterConstruction;
    Cardinal vmtBeforeDestruction;
    Cardinal vmtDispatch;
    Cardinal vmtDefaultHandler;
    Cardinal vmtNewInstance;
    Cardinal vmtFreeInstance;
    Cardinal vmtDestroy;
};
```

Where cardinal is unsigned int. The problem is that after using "Right Click > Struct offset" on top of the number 44 it generates the following result:

```
Result = *(Self - offsetof(VMT_ClassDefinition, vmtSafeCallException));
```

I was doing what is said in [New features in Hex-Rays Decompiler 1.6](https://hex-rays.com/blog/new-features-in-hex-rays-decompiler-1-6/) section 3, but as you can see the expected result and what I got is totally different.

My guess is that it forgets about the "-" sign and just advances from the start +44. Is there a way to reverse this behavior? I know it can be done in ASM view by inverting with "_" and then pressing "T" like in [Negated structure offsets](https://hex-rays.com/blog/negated-structure-offsets/), but that does not apply to the Pseudocode view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shifted pointer](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1695.shtml) should work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since there seems to be no other way I ended up converting the Self variable into a pointer to the struct and IDA generated the following code:

```
Self[-1].vmtClassName
```

At least it is readable now.